# Python to Perl - Calculate term relatedness

Tags: python-2.7, perl

I am trying to find a way to calculate the relatedness of two terms in Python, but I could only find ways to calculate the similarity.

I found
[a Perl script](https://manned.org/WordNet::Similarity::hso/e763c92c) that seems to do the job:

```
     use WordNet::Similarity::hso;

     use WordNet::QueryData;

     my $wn = WordNet::QueryData->new();

     my $object = WordNet::Similarity::hso->new($wn);

     my $value = $object->getRelatedness("car#n#1", "bus#n#2");

     ($error, $errorString) = $object->getError();

     die "$errorString\n" if($error);

     print "car (sense 1) <-> bus (sense 2) = $value\n";
```

I tried to write a Python wrapper around the Perl script:

```
import subprocess

set1 = 'church#n#1'
set2 = 'temple#n#1'
cmd = ['perl', './sample.pl', set1, set2]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)


for line in proc.stdout:
    if 'Similarity' in line:
        similarity = int(line.split("=")[-1])
print similarity
```

I have installed perl v.5.26.1 from binary, but when I run my Python script I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "asdf/sshso.py", line 6, in <module> proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__ errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
```

I know that my Python/Perl combination has errors and can't work.

I can figure that out as the Perl code doesn't seem too complicated. I'm just looking for a way to parse my Python words to the Perl script and get back my calculated *relatedness value*.

I have to do this for 44,000 items, so performance is important.

Comment: *"Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden*": what is that in english?

Comment: @HåkonHægland "The system cannot find the specified file."

Comment: I don't think the error is related to perl. If I run `perl ./sample.pl foo bar` from the command prompt, I get `Can't open perl script "./sample.pl": No such file or directory`. The error you're getting looks like a Python exception, probably because it can't find `perl`.

Comment: What happens if you change your code to `cmd = ['perl', '-E', 'say "Similarity=42"']`?

Comment: @melpomene i get 42 printed out

Comment: If you want speed, either read the perl source and port the algorithm to Python, write your application in Perl, or write a perl process that will be loaded once and then hang around to handle multiple translations and talk to it from your python code.

Comment: The error could also indicate that perl cannot find the `./sample.pl` file. Note that for a relative path, the `sample.pl` file must be in the current working directory where you run the Python script. Can you use an absolute path instead? E.g. `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'sample.pl')`.